# Dual boot : Accessing other Ubuntu version

Tags: ssh, dualboot

I would like to install a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 on my machine.

But for example if i boot on 20.04, is there a way to open a session through the terminal to the 18.04 version (as when connecting with ssh to another machine) to be able to execute commands and share files between the two versions ?

Comment: Sharing and networking between machines is best and most easily done with virtual machines.

Comment: Yes thank you i didn't think about virtual machine

Comment: Dual booting cannot *run* two systems at the same time on the bare metal hardware. Only one operating system can run at a time. You could potentially mount the filesystem of the alternate system in the running one, but not ssh into it as it would not be running. If you want two machines *running* at the same time then as mentioned running them both as VM guests, or one as a host and the other as guest could work, though that is virtualisation, not dual-booting.

Comment: If you have a decent PC and a fast (7200-rpm or SSD) drive, you can install VMware Workstation (best) or Virtual Box on Ubuntu 20.04 (assuming that to be the workhorse version) and then install Ubuntu 18 as a guest. You can readily network between the two.